# german charset in delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

hi i made an application with an option for translation in german but when i test it it show the ß as strange symbols and also ü and others are going bad.
Is there a way to set german character to show correctly??

Comment: Delphi 2007 doesn't really support internationalization well. It would be much easier if you upgraded to Delphi XE.

Comment: oke but isnt there really a way to do that? other then upgrading?

Comment: You can attempt to make an app work with ANSI strings, but it's an enormous bind and it works trivially out of the box with Delphi 2009 and greater.

Comment: Having Tschüß as caption on a TButton or a TForm works just fine for me in D2007.

Comment: Strange; the chars you've mentioned are standard ANSI [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) so this should work

Comment: Making sure every single control uses the proper CHARSET and making sure every AnsiString constant is encoded using the proper code page is going to take a lot of work. I second David's opinion: Doing it all with D2007 doesn't make sense, upgrade to Delphi XE and you get full Unicode support. You need to put in a lot of work either way, but putting that effort towards Delphi 2007 is almost waisted energy since it's useless once you upgrade to Unicode. And the upgrade to Unicode is unavoidable, you can't hope to stay on D2007 for ever!

Comment: While I am not surprised when an english-only Delphi user is hesitant to embrace unicode, I am almost shocked when a European non-english speaker who has made a translation of one of his/her apps seems reluctant to embrace unicode.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you use the correct codes for these characters, you have to make sure that Windows uses the correct codepage 850 or Windows-1252. If you want me to test something on a German Windows...

Comment: well i want the chars to show without using a german windows and i already set the DBText to use the ANSI_CHARSET but that didnt work

Comment: There is still a chance that the characters are not properly coded, because they may have been entered in a different codepage. Hard to tell without any data.

Comment: @ deamon i get the values from a stored procedure  and the collation of my database is set as SQL_Latin1_General_CPI_CI_AS

Comment: Are you trying to store Non-Latin-1 symbols into your database?

Comment: @Marijn, set your database tables to use UTF8, this will fix the problems with storing non-latin1 symbols in fields.